# using sed to delete matching line from multiple text files

Tags: file-io, sed

All files in a directory of my project has one line:

```
var $useDbConfig = 'default_dev';
```

How can I delete this line from all files and then save the same file, with a single line command using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `sed` version supports the `-i` option you could use this command to interactively delete the line from all files in current directory:

```
sed -i "/var \$useDbConfig = 'default_dev';/d" ./*
```

Furthermore: The way to quote the string works in `bash`. In other shells (like `csh`) you should adjust the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

you may try

```
sed -i.bak '/var \$useDbConfig = .*default_dev.*;/d' *
```

or you can use `awk`

```
awk '/var/&&/\$useDbConfig/&&/default_dev/{next}{print $0>FilENAME}' *
```

Comment: You were some seconds faster ;)

Comment: You should have warned me, as a noob, that it will generate a hell lot of filename.bak. :)
I had to replace the last '*' with '*.php', after sed error:  "sed: couldn't edit <sub-dir-name>: not a regular file." Thanks!

Comment: @pMan, oops, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` argument to `sed` edits in place. With an argument, it saves a backup. So you want something like this:

```
STR="var $useDbConfig = 'default_dev';"
sed -i.bak "/$STR/d" *
```